# Need logic: "If URL parameter exists, post same URL parameter on all webpage href links."

Tags: php, url, parameters

I'm trying to figure out how to post URL parameters on all href links if a certain URL parameter exists. For example, say I'm on http://myWebSite.com?ID=123, I want all internal or external href links on that page to also carry URL parameter "?ID=123".

Here are some sample href links you might find on my homepage, and with some logic, I want those links to carry the captured URL parameter.

> myWebSite.com/about ---> myWebSite.com/about?ID=123
>   myWebSite.com/contact ---> myWebSite.com/contact?ID=123
>   twitter.com/cmF ---> twitter.com/cmF?ID=123

```
if(isset($_GET['ID']))
{
   // Post ID URL parameter to all href links
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [output_add_rewrite_var](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.output-add-rewrite-var.php) for this purpose.

> This function adds another name/value pair to the URL rewrite
>   mechanism. The name and value will be added to URLs (as GET parameter)
>   and forms (as hidden input fields) the same way as the session ID when
>   transparent URL rewriting is enabled with session.use_trans_sid.
>   Please note that absolute URLs (http://example.com/..) aren't
>   rewritten.

This can be used like:

```
<!-- index.php -->
<?PHP
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    output_add_rewrite_var("id", $_GET['id']);
}
?>
<a href="./test.php">Test url</a>
```

PHP will rewrite this to the following when calling the script via `index.php?id=1234`:

```
<a href="./test.php?id=1234">Test url</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @ferrybig. I've tested this and it's almost perfect, but what about outbound links? That's the other important piece. How do I add that id to `<a href="http://google.com">` for example?